# Add/change/remove elements in tkinter when specific dropdown menu item is selected

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am trying to create a "programme" where you can click a calculate button, and then it will calculate and show a plot of some data that are dependent on some options a user chooses, i.e. dropdown menus, input fields, etc.

I have the following code:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class MainPlot:
    def __init__(self, frame1):

        self.frame1 = frame1

        self.frame1a = Frame(frame1)
        self.frame1a.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.frame1b = Frame(frame1)
        self.frame1b.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        options2 = ["var1", "var2", "var3"]
        self.variable2 = StringVar()
        self.variable2.set("var1") # default value
        self.w2 = OptionMenu(self.frame1a, self.variable2, *options2)
        self.w2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NW, ipadx=5)

        # Variables
        if self.variable2.get() == "var1":
            self.equipment = {"var11": False,
                        "var12": True,
                        "var13": True,
                        "var14": True
            }

        elif self.variable2.get() == "var2":
            self.equipment = {"var21": False,
                        "var22": True,
                        "var23": False
            }

        
        # Available nodes
        self.available_nodes = Label(self.frame1a, text="Available nodes:")
        self.available_nodes.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=NW, pady=(10, 0))
        
        self.CheckVar, self.C = dict(), dict()
        for i, (key, value) in enumerate(self.equipment.items()):
            self.CheckVar[key] = IntVar(self.frame1a)
            self.CheckVar[key].set(value)
            self.C[key] = Checkbutton(self.frame1a, text = key, variable=self.CheckVar[key], onvalue = True, offvalue = False, command=lambda: self.equipment[key].__setitem__(1, self.CheckVar[key].get()))
            self.C[key].grid(row=2+i, column=0, sticky=NW)

        # Separator
        tkinter.ttk.Separator(self.frame1a, orient=HORIZONTAL).grid(column=0, row=3+len(self.equipment), rowspan=1, sticky='we', pady=15, padx=5)

        # Calculate button
        self.button1 = Button(self.frame1a, text="Calculate") 
        self.button1.grid(row=4+len(self.equipment), column=0, sticky=N, ipady=5, ipadx=10, padx=2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk(className='Testing')
    root.geometry("1920x1080")
    aframe = Frame(root)
    mainplot = MainPlot(aframe)
    aframe.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH) 

    root.mainloop()
```

What I would like to do is that when I select a different option in the dropdown menu, the resulting checkboxes (created from the `if`, `elif` statements and dictionaries at `# Variables`) changes accordingly.

How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Why not give a command to option menu? It would be better to just give your code as whole, instead of posting fragments of it.

Comment: Sorry. I have now updated my question with the entire code, which should be able to run if packages are installed.